# When mentioning two people in a sentence, what's the proper way to use a pronoun to reference the first?

Tags: voice

Example:

> A fighter is someone who fights for the pleasure of the spectator, against his or her own safety.

How can I clearly show that `his or her` refers to the fighter and not the master?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I despise "his or her."  It's so bad, it should be unconstitutional.  Randomly switching "his" and "her" from sentence to sentence is almost as bad.  If you're making a general statement, and you think exclusively using "his" is sexist, then use the plural.

> Fighters fight for the pleasure of the spectator, against their own
>   safety.

Comment: I use plural instead of "his/her" *all the time*, so yes, excellent suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Change something else in the sentence.

> > A fighter is someone who fights for the pleasure of spectators, against his or her own safety.
> >
> > A fighter is someone who fights for the pleasure of the audience, against his or her own safety.

Comment: "his or her" is extremely awkward. Also delete "is someone who": **A fighter fights for the pleasure of the audience, against her own safety.** Simply distibute male and female examples evenly and without sexist bias throughout the text, and you can avoid "his or her".